# Error while installing sentry `unable to execute 'clang': No such file or directory`

Tags: installation, virtualenv, sentry

I am trying to install sentry by following the instruction from the [link](https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/python/): 
However when I try to execute command **pip install -U sentry**, I receive the error `InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /webapps/sentry/env/build/symsynd`

Here is the detail from log file:

```
 self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/webapps/sentry/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1003, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with 1
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    unable to execute 'clang': No such file or directory

unable to execute 'clang': No such file or directory



    No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options

    passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.

    See the error messages above.
```

It would be nice if someone can figure out what am I doing wrong.

Thank you,
Vady

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a C compiler to build the *symsynd* dependency.

If you are on a Debian based distribution (Ubuntu, etc.) just do :

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

Comment: I found that I also needed to install `cmake` (`apt-get install cmake`) to successfully complete the Sentry installation process.

Comment: also, make sure cmake verison is  CMake 3.4.3 or higher is required. the default on ubuntu repo is 2.8.make sure to change that too. https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-3.x

Answer (score 0):

It seems that specifying a C compiler will be ok, but not. In some packages clang is hard-coded. The only way is to install clang.